# Passing data into chart using HTML and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, charts

The following code is used to display a chart. The problem is the "data" is hard coded in. How can I change this so that the chart displays values which are displayed using:

```
<div id="name"> </div>
<div id="testscore"></div>
```

The above 2 div's contain dynamic values. I want to display these values in the chart.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function () {
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
    {
//      title:{
//        text: "Olympic Medals of all Times (till 2012 Olympics)"
//      },
      animationEnabled: true,
      legend: {
        cursor:"pointer",
        itemclick : function(e) {
          if (typeof (e.dataSeries.visible) === "undefined" || e.dataSeries.visible) {
              e.dataSeries.visible = false;
          }
          else {
              e.dataSeries.visible = true;
          }
          chart.render();
        }
      },
      axisY: {
        title: "Time"
      },
      toolTip: {
        shared: true,  
        content: function(e){
          var str = '';
          var total = 0 ;
          var str3;
          var str2 ;
          for (var i = 0; i < e.entries.length; i++){
            var  str1 = "<span style= 'color:"+e.entries[i].dataSeries.color + "'> " + e.entries[i].dataSeries.name + "</span>: <strong>"+  e.entries[i].dataPoint.y + "</strong> <br/>" ; 
            total = e.entries[i].dataPoint.y + total;
            str = str.concat(str1);
          }
          str2 = "<span style = 'color:DodgerBlue; '><strong>"+e.entries[0].dataPoint.label + "</strong></span><br/>";
          str3 = "<span style = 'color:Tomato '>Total: </span><strong>" + total + "</strong><br/>";

          return (str2.concat(str)).concat(str3);
        }

      },
      data: [
      {        
        type: "bar",
        showInLegend: true,
        name: "Black",
        color: "#000000",
        dataPoints: [
        { y: 0.18, label: "Name"},
        { y: 0.12, label: "Name 1"},
        { y: 0.59, label: "Name 2"},        
        { y: 1.15, label: "Name 3"},        



        ]
      },
      ]
    });

chart.render();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call

```
var data = document.getElementById('name').value;
var data2 = document.getElementById('testscore').value;
```

If it's a single value, it would work; otherwise, you need to do it this way:

```
var array = $('#your.id').data('stuff');
```

Here, "stuff" is nothing but

```
<div data-stuff="some data" ></div>
```

Or, create an array by:

```
var array = new Array();
```

and finally, store the data into the array.

Comment: so in the JavaScript, how would i set the datapoints to display these elements?

Comment: Pass data and data2 variable name as per my example. So like datapoints : data. Also check in console inspect element tab if you are getting the data in right format by typing co sole.log(data);